# Problema de archivos en POO -- main.cpp Punto.h y Punto.cpp

Tags: c++, poo, archivo, librería

Tengo 3 archivos

El primero es este que se llama **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Punto.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Punto* p1 = new Punto();//creacion de un objeto dinamico

    p1->setX(5);
    p1->setY(8);

    cout<<"El valor de X es: "<<p2->getX()<<endl;
    cout<<"El valor de Y es: "<<p2->getY()<<endl;  

    return 0;
}
```

El segundo se llama **Punto.h**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Punto{
    private:
        int x,y;
    public:
        Punto(int _x,int _y){//incializar atributos Constructo 1
            x =_x;
            y = _y;
        }
        Punto(){//Constructor2
            x = y = 0;
        }
        void setX(int valorX);//Establecer el valor de X - //acceder a x
        void setY(int valorY);
        int getX();
        int getY();//obtener valor de x y y
};
```

El tercero se llama **Punto.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Punto.h"

using namespace std;

void Punto::setX(int valorX){
    x = valorX;
}

void Punto::setY(int valorY){
    y = valorY;
}

int Punto::getX(){
    return x;
}

int Punto::getY(){
    return y;
}
```

Mi inconveniente es que cuando quiero compilar el archivo **main.cpp** me manda un error, entonces debo de pasar las funciones de el archivo **Punto.cpp** al **Punto.h** y me compila, pero en un canal de youtube vi que los separa en 3 archivos y le compila bien.

¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: Falta detalles en esta pregunta. ¿Qué compilador estás usando? ¿Qué error sale? ¿Es un error del compilador? ¿Es un error del enlazador? ¿Estás compilando desde el *shell*? Sí es así, ¿qué comando le pasaste al compilador? Con este comando debería de compilar y enlazar con éxito: `g++ -o myExe main.cpp Punto.cpp` (crea un ejecutable llamado `myExe`). Claro esto solo funcionará si usas el compilador **g++**.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 problemas el primero es que declaraste un objeto llamado `p1` y cuando haces uso de los metodos lo llamas `p2`, y al no haber ningun objeto llamado p2 lanza un error.

El otro problema es que solo abris el archivo `main.cpp` que incluye al archivo
`Punto.h` que es donde estan declaradas las funciones, pero este archvivo no puede encontrar donde estan definidas las funciones por ende lanza errores, la solucion seria crear un proyecto en el IDE que estes trabajando, añadir los 3 archivos y luego compilar.

Answer (score 0):

En principio llamas a una variable `p2` cuando la declaraste como `p1`, pero es solo cuestión de el nombre. El problema de que no compile es porque C y C++ tienen el concepto de "unidad de compilación", este es el archivo fuente con el que se invocó el compilador y todo el código de los `#include`. Por ende deberas copilar tu codigo con el comando `g++` e incluyendo todos los archivos: (ejemplo)

```
C:/folder$ g++ main.cpp Punto.h Punto.cpp
```

Y esto ya compilara tu código correctamente :)